# Rails 4 nested routes without all RESTful routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, activerecord, rails-routing

I have a `SchedulesController` which corresponds to a `Schedule` class which is not an ActiveRecord model.  The only action in `SchedulesController` is `show`.

Then I have a `Shift` ActiveRecord model and a `ShiftsController`.

In the `schedules/show` view, there is a link the user can click to bring in a form for a new `Shift`.  This form is retrieved from the `ShiftsController` via an ajax request.  Because the request url will be packaged as `schedules/shifts/new`, I need the `shifts` routes to be nested within the `schedules` routes.

However, I'd like to avoid generating all the RESTful routes for `schedules`, just to keep things clean.  I only need `show`.  This takes care of that:

```
# config/routes.rb

get "schedules/show"
resources :schedules, only: [] do
  collection do
    resources :shifts
  end
end
```

Note that I use `get "schedules/show"` because I don't want `show` to be handled the usual way, where it requires an ID.  I might change the `show` action to `display` to resolve that confusion.  Anyway, here are the routes that this generates:

```
$ rake routes
Prefix         Verb   URI Pattern                          Controller#Action
schedules_show GET    /schedules/show(.:format)            schedules#show
shifts         GET    /schedules/shifts(.:format)          shifts#index
               POST   /schedules/shifts(.:format)          shifts#create
new_shift      GET    /schedules/shifts/new(.:format)      shifts#new
edit_shift     GET    /schedules/shifts/:id/edit(.:format) shifts#edit
shift          GET    /schedules/shifts/:id(.:format)      shifts#show
               PATCH  /schedules/shifts/:id(.:format)      shifts#update
               PUT    /schedules/shifts/:id(.:format)      shifts#update
               DELETE /schedules/shifts/:id(.:format)      shifts#destroy
```

This solution works; I can pull in the `new_shift` form on the `schedules/show` page.  The problem is that it creates all the RESTful routes for `schedules/shifts`, and I only need one right now, `new`.  So I tried this:

```
# config/routes.rb

get "schedule/show"
resources :schedules, only: [] do
  collection do
    resources :shifts, only: [:new]
  end
end
```

And that's where I run into a problem.  Here are the routes:

```
$ rake routes
Prefix         Verb URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
schedules_show GET  /schedules/show(.:format)       schedules#show
new_shift      GET  /schedules/shifts/new(.:format) shifts#new
```

That looks okay to me (?).  But when I go to the `schedules/show` page and click the link that's supposed to bring in the `new_shift` form, I get this exception:

```
Started GET "/schedules/shifts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-29 19:59:52 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ShiftsController#new as HTML
  Rendered shifts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (135.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 272ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `shifts_path' for #<#<Class:0x7578de90>:0x7578d4d0>):
    1: <%= form_for @shift do |f| %>
    2:   <%= f.text_field :start_time %>
    3:   <%= f.text_field :end_time %>
    4: <% end %>
  app/views/shifts/new.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shifts_new_html_erb__535553616_985195992'
  app/controllers/shifts_controller.rb:8:in `new'
```

I assume `#<#<Class:0x7578de90>:0x7578d4d0>` refers to my `Schedule` class, which as I said above is not an ActiveRecord model.  But why does it not work here, but does when I do it the other way?  In both cases, the `GET /schedules/shifts/new(.:format)` route is exactly the same when I run `rake routes`.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Rails conventions, your form is trying to do a POST request to a path named `shifts_path`, only it cannot find that path method because there isn't a route defined for the `#create` action.

You need a route for `#create` as well as `#new`.

```
resources :shifts, only: [:new, :create]
```